# How to create Monocle lenses with sequences?

Tags: scala, scalaxb, monocle-scala

I am trying to create a Monocle lens with nested case classes and sequences.

```
import monocle.macros.GenLens
import monocle.function.Each.each

case class A(bs: Seq[B])
case class B(c: Int)

val bs = GenLens[A](_.bs)
val c = GenLens[B](_.c)

val cs = (bs composeTraversal each composeLens c)
```

Compilation fails on the last line. I am using Monocle 1.5.0-cats.

PS: replacing `Seq[B]` by `List[B]` works, but my case classes are generated by scalaxb, which uses sequences.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not a "real answer" but I also have issues with Seq in Monokle. I get exactly the same answer from my very experienced colleague:
"There is no support to Seq from Cats. This is the reason good enough to not use it. Use Vector as the Seq default implementation". :(

Comment: Lol, I came here from google search to find my own response for the issue I forgot.